# Cannot deploy file . no license installed artifactory offline

Tags: windows, artifactory, license-key

My operation system is windows 10/7...
I am trying to upload an Npm file to the Artifactory server.
I am working offline and I have an old license so I edit the date of the server...

it seems that I can use all the permissions , but when I tried to upload the tgz file to the Artifactory server it throw an error ("cannot deploy file "***". No license installed!.

so I tried to deploy a random file to the maven repository and it throw the same error … so how can I make the offline old license work...

and again the seems that the license work (like an admin and repositories) nut when I deploy some thing it throw an error.

my operation system is windows 10/7...

thank you.

Comment: -1. Artifactory licenses are cryptographically signed specifically to prevent people from doing things like this. Your question is essentially "I changed the expiration date on my driver's license with sharpie marker, but I still got arrested. How do I forge my license well enough that it fools the officer?"

Answer (score 4):

Tampering with the license files or using expired licenses is a violation of the JFrog EULA, so that's not something anyone should ever recommend. The only valid option to make it work is to get a new license. To do that you can contact JFrog at sales [at] jfrog.com.